@PathVariable being Null Leads to No endpoint GET error
I'm currently Upgrading a Spring Boot Project from Version 2.5.9 to 3.3.1
It has Controllers defined as below.
@GetMapping("/devices/{cId}/model/{sId}/deviceList")
public ResponseEntity<DeviceListDTO> getDeviceList( @PathVariable(required = true) final String cId,
        @PathVariable(required = true) final String sId) {
    
    if (cId == null || sId == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

There are several unit tests which pass sId as null.
In spring boot 2.5.9 controller returns a 404 as expected. But After upgrading to Spring boot 3.3.1, The request does not hit the controller at all, Instead it returns a error as No endpoint GET /api/v1/devices/myCid/model//deviceList
I've tried adding a controllerAdvice for exception MissingPathVariableException, but that doesn't seem to work as well.
Any Advice on how to fix this or it it simply not possible with the new Spring Boot 3.3.1 version.

isn't that some bug fixed? Expecting it to get inside controller when required is set to true is strange.

@hi_my_name_is So how can you change default way of handling that exception?

I would start with required=false to see if spring will allow request to get inside controller, if so - you get 404

Why are you getting double /?

It is model//deviceList ?

@NguyenManhCuong Because path variable sId is null.

at Spring 2.5.x This version, PathVariable is not care much about the null path, so that it always return 404 but since 3.2.x Spring recommend to use NotNull due to each Component in Spring is being initial before any request, so this may lead to always null. And a Null Path is an error (exception)

It seem to be impossible at current Spring Boot version.
